# WPF Prism Load XML in module

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism

i am experimenting with prism and the possibilities it brings to create applications divided into modules.
In one of my modules i want to load data from a XML file but can't get it to work so that

```
Uri uri = new Uri(resourceFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```

will  look for the file in the "Data" folder of my module project. Instead the file is successfully loaded if i put the "Data" folder with the XMl file inside the Shell project.

What do i miss?

Edit: value of resourceFile: "Data/file.xml"

Comment: What is the value of `resourceFile` variable in both cases?

Comment: at the moment the value is "Data/file.xml". Edited the question and added this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got that to work:

`Uri uri = new Uri("MainModule1;component/" + resourceFile, UriKind.Relative);`

actually i did try that before but must have made a mistake.